# Button is being triggered by spacebar after clicked once

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field:

```
<input id="audio_file" type="file" accept="audio/*" />
```

my problem is that once I've clicked it, if I press space after that it simulates the input being clicked again.  How do I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once clicked, the element gets a keyboard focus. And the next time you press the space bar or enter "click" occurs again. If you need to avoid it, simply remove the keyboard focus of the element using the [`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur) function.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let input = document.querySelector("input");
  input.addEventListener("click", () => input.blur());
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.onkeyup = function(e){ if(e.keyCode == 32){  } }`

Handle space bar press maybe? Then just don't execute any code.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to avoid handling keypresses globally, you could use jQuery to prevent the default onClick event for that specific button.  Something like:

```
$("#audio_file").on("click", function(e) { 
    if (e.originalEvent.detail == 0)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Edit: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5L01kjkk/